# Auto Connect to WPA Personal WiFi on startup | Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, netplan, wpa-supplicant

I've set up Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS on a PC to install a medical software for use in my clinic in Ethiopia.

I wanted to connect it to a WPA Personal wireless network.
Since I don't have an Ethernet port, I've downloaded wpa_supplicant on a USB and installed it from there.
I've followed the instructions on https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant on how to configure wpa_supplicant and to auto connect the server to WiFi on startup.

I did not configure Netplan (which has only a file named 50-cloud-init.yaml).
I only followed the guide on that website.

I've been able to connect it to the WiFi and obtain an IP address but after rebooting no IP address was assigned and when I ran the "sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s0", I got the following error:

[image]

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Do you have the wpasupplicant package installed? It is not installed by default as part of Ubuntu Server.  Without this package, wifi will not work.

Comment: Hi, kindly take a look at the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages show that the key you're passing to wpasupplicant is rejected by the AP.   You should double check that you have the correct key.

Once you have this working, you should be able to implement the configuration in netplan. I find netplan easier to configure than wpasupplicant.